# Morphing Modal Window broke all background fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity, morphing

I have found a nice morphing modal script that I am trying to add into website. Everything is working fine, but then I noticed that, after I close a window, all my background was broken.

Can someone help me solve this issue or at least give some hints on what can be causing this?

website: http://ochutnejvietnam.cz/test

click to "Fire Modal Window", then "close it" and check a "background".

Comment: Please use tags for others users to reference. What browser are you? I notice nothing wrong in Chrome.

Comment: Please post code you need help with here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the background, that is the way it was meant to work, the glitch is because when you open the modal the scroll bar (right) is hiding, when you close the modal the scroll bar goes visible again and the background image resizes to fit on the new size of the view.

Another problem with your website, when you scroll down with the modal opened the background fixed images appear over the modal, you can change that by removing the z-index from the class .bg-fixed .